# Ising model: Entropy as derivative of free energy

Tags: mathematical-physics, information-theory, machine-learning

I'm trying to prove the following relation, related to the Ising model.

$S = -\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}$, where $S$ denotes the entropy, $F = -kT \ln Z$ the free energy, and $kT = 1/\beta$. 
It is worth mentioning that this is my first encounter with the Ising model. I think I am overlooking something obvious, and I'm hoping someone could provide me with a hint or explanation.

If we just compute the derivative using the formula's given, we find:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{\partial (-kT\ln Z)}{\partial T} &=& -k \ln Z - kT \frac{\partial \ln Z}{\partial T}\\&=&-k \ln Z - kT\cdot\left( \frac{1}{Z(\beta)} \cdot \frac{1}{kT^2}\cdot \sum_x E(x)\exp(-\beta E(x)) \right)\\&=&-k \ln Z - \frac{1}{T}\cdot\left( \sum_x E(x)\cdot p(x) \right)\\&=&-k \ln Z - k\beta \cdot \bar{E}(\beta) = -k\cdot S\end{eqnarray*}$$

As you can see, I'm off by a factor $k$ on the derivative. Sure, for $k = 1$ [which is the case the literature considered so far] the relation holds. 
I've proven before that $S$ satisfies
$$ S = \ln Z + \beta \bar{E}(\beta) $$.

Can someone provide me with a hint as to why my derivation is wrong?

Comment: nothing you said is specific to the Ising model.  Any thermodynamics textbook would do.  I am curious -- if you have a specific machine learning problem in mind

Comment: No, I do not (yet). I'm doing a course in machine learning which covers this model.

Comment: any link to materials what book is he using? free free to post here or http://cs.stackexchange.com/ or http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: We're using Information Theory, Inference and Learning Algorithms from David MacKay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entropy has units of J/K, so your previous derivation is wrong. Everything else here is fine.

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot.